# How to set a constant in aurelia by environment

Tags: aurelia

I'd like my API's base URL to change from `dev` to `prod`. In Angular I user to use a `config.json` file which was later injected into the app using `grunt-env`

Comment: This is a pretty open question because it all depends on how you are serving and could definitely be up to personal choice.  I don't see anything wrong with putting it in a `json` file

Comment: I wouldn't want to read that json file over and over again - it would make more sense to inject it once (somewhere) in the config

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant just use the http client to read it one time should be super simple.

Comment: Thanks PW Kad, any chance you have a gist with an example of how to do it in practice?

Answer (score 20):

If you use the [Aurelia CLI](https://github.com/aurelia/cli), it will generate an `environments` directory inside of your `aurelia_project`.

Within this directory you can setup environmental configs that will be copied into environment.js in your `src` directory based the `--env [dev/stage/prod]` flag that you pass into your `au build/run` commands.

Then you can use `import environment from './environment'` to access your environment specific configuration values.

Another option that you can look into is the [Aurelia Configuration Plugin](https://github.com/Vheissu/Aurelia-Configuration), which also has dynamic environmental configs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to 'inject' it only once then what is stopping you from using a simple ES6 module ? It should be loaded only once from the server.

For instance you could something like that in a config.js file : (warning ! I didn't try to run it)

```
export var Config = {
    path : 'path to find'
};
```

you can then use your module anywhere you need it :

```
import {Config} from 'config';
```

Comment: Yes, injected once - but _different_ values when running locally, and when running on production. In Angular + grunt, I used `grunt serve` to be DEV constants, and `grunt build` to be production constants.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used the Aurelia-Configuration plugin to dynamically switch environments based on the domain that hosts the app

More info [https://github.com/Vheissu/Aurelia-Configuration/blob/master/README.md#get-started to do this](https://github.com/Vheissu/Aurelia-Configuration/blob/master/README.md#get-started%20to%20do%20this)