# aurelia, application settings (such as base api url) per environment with webpack

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to set a different base URL for API based on webpack environment setting.

I'm using the webpack typescript navigation skeleton, and I've tried some methods using the DefinePlugin manually in the webpack config, but haven't been able to get variables to get replaced by webpack.

This is basically same question as [How to set a constant in aurelia by environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722814/how-to-set-a-constant-in-aurelia-by-environment), which has an answer in terms of the au cli, but I'd like to find solution specific to the new webpack skeleton using easy webpack.  It would be nice to have an example with easy webpack.

Anyone out there doing this successfully already using webpack navigation skeleton?