# Environmental-based switching of endpoints in Aurelia-API

Tags: aurelia

I have two endpoints for aurelia-api that are registered in **main.js**. One points to my staging server, the other points to my local development server (Kestrel).

What is the recommended way to **register endpoints or set the default endpoint so that  I can switch between them easily based on environments**?

```
.plugin('aurelia-api', config => {
  config
   //.registerEndpoint('api', 'http://localhost:5000/api/')      
    .registerEndpoint('api', 'http://server:port/api/')

    .setDefaultEndpoint('api');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to configure anything based on your environment is by utilising the `environments` folder, that Aurelia creates when you start your app, containing a `dev` and a `prod` environment.

dev.ts :

```
export default {
  debug: true,
  testing: true,
  endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/api"
}
```

prod.ts

```
export default {
  debug: false,
  testing: false,
  endpoint: "http://server:port/api/"
}
```

These compile to the file `environment.ts`, based on whether you're running it locally or on the server.

If you inject the environment into your file, you are able to use any variable specified in it, like so:

```
import environment from "./environment";

export function configure(aurelia) {
 aurelia.use
  .plugin('aurelia-api', config => {
  config 
    .registerEndpoint('api', environment.endpoint)

    .setDefaultEndpoint('api');
})
```

Comment: More information about the `environment` files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722814/how-to-set-a-constant-in-aurelia-by-environment